# How do I add an IE URL to the Hyper-link when clicking that HyperLink

Tags: hyperlink

can you tell me how to add the IE tab URL when I click the hyperlink, meaning link + IE URL tab. ?

Please let me know.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you want your links to open in a new tab.

You can do this by specifying the `target` attribute with the `_blank` value.

```
<a href="mypage.html" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```